# Insert element to circular list using scheme

Tags: list, insert, scheme, circular-list

I have a circular list, eg: #0=(1 2 3 4 . #0#).

What I want to do is to insert a new element (x) into this list so that the outcome is #0=(x 1 2 3 4 . #0#). I have been trying using this code (x is the circular list):

```
(define (insert! elm)
  (let ((temp x))
    (set-car! x elm)
    (set-cdr! x temp)))
```

However, I think that set-cdr! is not working like I want it to. What am I missing here? Maybe I am way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to prepend an element to a list is to *modify* the car of the list, and set the cdr of the list to a new cons whose car is the original first element of the list and whose cdr is the original tail of the list:

```
(define (prepend! x list)                      ; list = (a . (b ...)) 
  (set-cdr! list (cons (car list) (cdr list))) ; list = (a . (a . (b ...)))
  (set-car! list x))                           ; list = (x . (a . (b ...)))
```

```
(let ((l (list 1 2 3)))
  (prepend! 'x l)
  (display l))
;=> (x 1 2 3)
```

Now, that will still work with circular lists, because the cons cell (i.e., pair) that is the beginning of the list remains the same, so the "final" cdr will still point back to object that is the beginning.  To test this, though, we need some functions to create and sample from circular lists, since they're not included in the language (as far as I know).

```
(define (make-circular list)
  (let loop ((tail list))
    (cond
      ((null? (cdr tail))
       (set-cdr! tail list)
       list)
      (else
       (loop (cdr tail))))))

(define (take n list)
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (car list)
            (take (- n 1)
                  (cdr list)))))
```

```
(display (take 10 (make-circular (list 1 2 3))))
;=> (1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

Now we can check what happens if we prepend to a circular list:

```
(let ((l (make-circular (list 1 2 3))))
  (prepend! 'x l)
  (display (take 15 l)))
;=> (x 1 2 3 x 1 2 3 x 1 2 3 x 1 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! I always find the solution to be much less complex than what I thought when it comes to scheme.

Comment: You're right, +1! I rarely use mutable lists, so this solution was non-obvious to me, but this is definitely better than my approach. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to prepend an element to a circular list, you need to do two things:

1. Insert a new cons cell at the front of the list containing the additional element. This is easy because you can just perform a simple `(cons elm x)`.
2. You also need to modify the recursive portion of the circular list to point at the newly created cons cell, otherwise the circular portion will only include the old parts of the list.

To perform the latter, you need a way to figure out where the "end" of the circular list is. This doesn't actually exist, since the list is, of course, circular, but it can be determined by performing an `eq?` check on each element of the list until it finds an element equal to the head of the list.

Creating a helper function to do this, a simple implementation of `insert!` would look like this:

```
(define (find-cdr v lst)
  (if (eq? v (cdr lst)) lst
      (find-cdr v (cdr lst))))

(define (insert! elm)
  (set! x (cons elm x))
  (set-cdr! (find-cdr (cdr x) (cdr x)) x))
```

Comment: I think this might be more complex than it needs to be.  Since the tail already wraps around, it's easier to modify the car of that cons, and to insert the new cons just after that one.  That makes the whole operation constant time, since you don't need to find the "end" of the list.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29593700/1281433) that demonstrates that approach.

Comment: Thank you for a good answer. However, I think I disagree with ur eq check. What will happen if u for instance have a circular list with two occurrences of the same symbol? Won't the eq check then be misinformed and believe that it has reached the end when it in reality it has found the second occurrence of the same symbol? EG: #0=(1 2 3 4 1 2 . #0#)

Comment: @Br0dskive No, Alexis's answer isn't comparing the element of the list;  it's actually comparing the actual *pair* or cons cell that is part of the structure of the list.  `(cdr lst)` is the *rest* of the list, i.e., another list.  So checking whether `(eq? v (cdr lst))` is true means checking whether the *list* v is the same as the *rest* list of lst.